# Search in extremely large files (Open Academic Graph / Microsoft Academic Graph)

Tags: c#, c++, c, python-3.x, microsoft-graph-api

i downloaded the three different MAG (Microsoft-Academic Graph)-Files

1. MAG venues (~ 10GB)
2. MAG papers (~ 30GB)
3. MAG authors (~ 30GB)

from [Open Academic Graph](https://www.openacademic.ai/oag/)

Now i want to search the ID from MAG-Authors-File in the MAG-Paper-Files to get more information about the publications of the author (~30GB).

The problem is:

I tried to search the ID in the file with Python like:

```
import ast
import timeit

with open("/Users/xyxz/Downloads/mag_authors_2/mag_authors_10.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        xy = ast.literal_eval(line)
        if(xy["id"] == "2806941709"):
            print(xy)
```

> Time: 85 seconds

Can someone help me to get more performant in the search?
Is C or C++ faster?

Comment: C may (with a really high probability) be faster,

Comment: Why not use the tools that come with your operating system, maybe `grep`?

Comment: @JCWasmx86 thx for your answer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, i need a script / executable. To give for example the name of the author / authorID / etc. to get the Information.

Comment: 4 languages choices it too broad, best to narrow to 1 (maybe 2)

Comment: Create sql database. Insetr the data there (it will take a while but is done only one time). Then create the queries. Will be much faster as databases have indexes.

Comment: You forgot some languages, like Java, Fortran and Ada.

Comment: @NotYourFan -- What I'm suggesting is for you to use the tools that are available to the OS you are targeting, instead of trying to hack together something in C++ that is probably less-efficient and has bugs.  The `grep` tool that comes with Unix/Linux based systems, and have Windows ports could have been used to give you your results.  Then it's just a matter of piping those results to your program.   What if you discovered that grep took 5 seconds to find the data, and your program, no matter how hard you tried to make it fast, takes 5 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can split a large file to multiple content, search in each content by multiple threads.
2. Use compiled regex or KMP search algo.